# Rank and min-max norm all variables in a dataset in r

Tags: r, transform, transformation

I am wanting to transform all but one of the variable in my dataset and include these new, transformed variables into a new dataset. I imagine this should not be that difficult, however I have been running into some issues. The transformation I am trying to do is a min-max norm of the rank. I have been running the following code:

```
#create min-max norm function
normalize <- function(x) {
    return((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
}

cols <- c(1:ncol(dt))
dt[cols] <- normalize(rank(dt[cols]))
```

However, when I run this code I receive the following error:

```
 Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing
```

I was wondering if someone could please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rank` and `normalize` both take vectors. You can't give them data frames.

`sapply` and `lapply` are the classic utilties for *apply*ing function to columns of a data frame. A couple ways to do it:

```
# one step with an anonymous function, calling both normalize and rank
dt[cols] = lapply(dt[cols], function(x) normalize(rank(x)))
```

However, your error seems to suggest that your `cols` object is a matrix or array. So make sure that `cols` is what you think it is. And the methods I mention above assume that `dt` is a `data.frame` (or `data.table`, or `tibble`). If `dt` is a `matrix`, `array`, or something else, they will not work as expected. Look at `str(dt)` to check (and perhaps edit that info in to your question if you still have problems).
    # two steps, one at a time
    dt[cols] = lapply(dt[cols], rank)
    dt[cols] = lapply(dt[cols], normalize)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!